# BASHFUL error running testmethod using ApexMocks (StubApi)

Tags: fflib, apexmock, stubapi

### Given fflib code that looks like

```
for (Contact c: contacts) {
  uow.registerEmail(someEmailMessage);
}
```

### With testmethod ApexMocks verify (which uses StubApi)

```
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,
                                       mocks
                                        .times(3)
                                        .description('1 email per contact')))
                    .registerEmail((Messaging.SingleEmailMessage) fflib_Match.anyObject());
```

### I get this exception

```
System.JSONException: ORA-20001:
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CMETAACCESS", line 680
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CMETAACCESS", line 872
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CMETAACCESS", line 823
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CEMAILTEMPLATE", line 1386
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CEMAILTEMPLATE", line 1452
ORA-06512: at line 1


{call cEmailTemplate.get_emailtemplate(?,?,?,?)}

{call cEmailTemplate.get_emailtemplate(?,?,?,?)} (through reference chain: common.api.soap.wsdl.SingleEmailMessage["templateName"])
13:08:31.4 (1243880233)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NoDataFoundException: Data Not Available: 
The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error.
```

**with Stacktrace**

```
Class.fflib_MethodVerifier.describe: line 148, column 1
Class.fflib_MethodVerifier.describe: line 128, column 1
Class.fflib_MethodVerifier.throwException: line 93, column 1
Class.fflib_AnyOrder.verify: line 48, column 1
Class.fflib_MethodVerifier.verifyMethodCall: line 20, column 1
Class.fflib_ApexMocks.verifyMethodCall: line 132, column 1
Class.fflib_ApexMocks.mockNonVoidMethod: line 256, column 1
Class.fflib_ApexMocks.handleMethodCall: line 83, column 1
Class.fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork__sfdc_ApexStub.registerEmail: line 284, column 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering this for posterity*

The method `fflib_MethodVerifier.describe(..)` tries to JSON.serialize an object of type `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` which is unserializable.

So, I have no idea what the deep root cause is but the fix was simple:

The code under test `uow.registerEmail` registered for commit in the unit-of-work four(4) emails:

```
for (Contact c: contacts) {  // contacts size = 4
  uow.registerEmail(someEmailMessage);
}
```

but the `mocks.Verify` was looking for three (3) emails to-be-committed

```
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,
                                       mocks
                                        .times(3) // did not match reality
                                        .description('1 email per contact')))
                    .registerEmail((Messaging.SingleEmailMessage) fflib_Match.anyObject());
```

Changing it to 4 (from 3) resolved the BASHFUL error:

```
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,
                                       mocks
                                         .times(4)  // match reality here!
                                         .description('1 email per contact')))
                    .registerEmail((Messaging.SingleEmailMessage) fflib_Match.anyObject());
```

I can imagine that native users of the StubAPI (i.e. not using the apexMocks framework) could encounter the same issue when mocking objects of type `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` but I didn't have the energy to set up that use case.